Dark theme randomly changing betwen apps on ubuntu 24.04
In a fresh ubuntu 24.04 install. Some apps are showing light theme (settings,files, calendar) and others are on dark theme (firefox, terminal).
Example:
Dark theme applied
Any help? :P

Found a solution?

Are you using NVIDIA driver? Cause it seems like a shared problem with this https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1cfcu62/dark_mode_selected_but_system_ui_remains_light/
